# Reading 4 columns into one array in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have 4 columns in a table. The columns are "water", "fire", "earth" and "wind".

I want to read those 4 columns and put them in an elements array, called whiteCards (of size 4).

Accomplishing it was easy using MySQL queries, but I'm not too sure how to do it with Hibernate.

My class has the field `private int[] whiteCards;` and the following getter/setter:

```
@Column(name = "white_cards")
public int[] getWhiteCards() {
    return whiteCards;
}

public void setWhiteCards(int[] whiteCards) {
    this.whiteCards = whiteCards;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the `@Column(name = "white_cards")` is wrong, but I'm not sure what to change it to.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. But I have a feeling that is not the question you'd like to see answered .... You may want to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks mate. Edited my question.

Comment: Every column must be mapped to a separate field. But nothing forbids you to add a getWhiteCards() method creating an array, populating it with the 4 fields, and returning it.

Comment: I see. Thought there would be a cleaner way to approach this. Thanks!

Comment: I really don't think your way is cleaner. How would you get just the fire? Is it clearer to write obj.getFire(), or obj.getWhiteCards()[1]? How would you query the entities with a given fire value? `select o from Obj o where o.fire = 42` is as clear as one can be. You wouldn't be able to do that if all the column values were stored in a single array field.

Comment: Uh I should've added a bit more information, sorry. The 4 elements act pretty much the same, you can think of them as "element0",...,"element3". I'm never going to use methods such as obj.getFire(). I am however going to use methods such as obj.getAllElements() or obj.setElement(index), where index is between 0 and 3.

Anyways, thanks for the answer! Wish I could upvote it x_x